# Disabled asp control doesn't render title as title

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, title

I am trying to use `jquery tooltip` on an `asp:Textbox`. The problem is that I can't manage to make the title tag render as a title. It keeps rendering as data-original-title. I am using `twitter bootstrap` which I think can be a reason to this behaviour.

I have tried adding "title" and "tooltip" to my textbox, I have tried adding textbox attribute "title" from code behind but nothing changed. This is how it looks when rendered (I have omitted all unnecessary code):

```
<input type="text" title data-original-title="My Text">
```

As you see, title is rendered, but with no data, and my actual text is placed in a new unwanted attribute. Below is what I want to accomplish for the jquery tooltip to work.

```
<input type="text" title="My Text">
```

I have to use an asp control, otherwise this wouldn't be an issue.
 Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I did not mention that the control is disabled, because I thought it wouldn't make any difference. But in fact I just realised it works fine on an enabled asp control.
Problem still remains though because it's only when the control is disabled that i need the tooltip.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit It's not possible to put asp.net code in jsfiddle :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Attributes` to set `title`

```
txtBox1.Attributes.Add("title", "My Text");
```

*OR*

```
txtBox1.Attributes["title"] = "My Text";
```

Comment: I like your answer but as stated I had already tried this. There is also an edit to the question.

Comment: What is your generated html as I can see the tooltip on disabled textbox, http://jsfiddle.net/Tnv6u/1/

Comment: I did show my generated html in the question: <input type="text" title data-original-title="My Text"> And you did not use an asp:TextBox as I could see.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not tested but i have an idea

```
<input type="text" data-getmytitle="your title">
//This is your element
function getmebinded()
{
$('input["data-getmytitle="your title""]').each(function()
{
    $(this)[0].title="your title";
});
}
//make your function that will bind title to your element
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var aa=getmebinded();
 });
// so now this will call your function of javascript after page has been loaded and your js also
```

this should be work tell me feedback about this  i hope this one will help you the simple logic is bind title after page and your js has been loaded...regards...:)

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I tried getting the input your way but the only thing that worked was $('input') which would give me all inputs. Anyhow, doing this gave me this output: <input name="zzz" type="text" value="xxx" id="yyy" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" title="" data-original-title="your title">. This means it changed the attribute data-original-title anyway. Really annoying! It feels like I am missing something really important here.

Comment: I am able to find the title if I use: $('input[title=test]'), and this changes the data-original-title. Data-original-title must be an attribute that is set after page is rendered and every js code is executed..

Comment: You can not set it because if you set that one then your jquery works my example is done can you provide me some details of that one?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.. What kind of details do you want me to share? What I am trying to say is that whatever way I try to change the _title_ it always changes the _data-original-title_.

Comment: I used the same code that you showed me but changed some things. For example, I had to omit the " signs to get the right input. This is the code: `$(document).ready(function() { var aa = getmebinded(); });` `function getmebinded() { $('input[title=test]').each(function () { $(this)[0].title = "theRightTitle"; }); }`

Comment: For clarification I also tried replacing "title" with "data-getmytitle" (as you adviced) and "data-original-title". Only the "title"-tag gives me a result, which means that the title attribute exists during javascript execution, but immediately after is changed to data-original-title.

Comment: Okay trying to cook someting for you it would be better that you chat or give me some source files